# In sync sliderInput and textInput

Tags: r, dynamic, textbox, shiny, slider

Consider the following shiny app:

```
library('shiny')

# User Interface/UI

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(
    'Slider and Text input update'
  ), # titlePanel

  mainPanel(

    # Slider input
    sliderInput(
      inputId = 'sliderValue',
      label = 'Slider value',
      min = 0,
      max = 1000,
      value = 500
    ), # sliderInput

    # Text input
    textInput(
      inputId = 'textValue',
      label = NULL
    ) # textInput

  ) # mainPanel

) # fluidPage


# Server logic

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    # Update vertical depth text box with value of slider
    updateTextInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = 'textValue',
      value = input$sliderValue
    ) # updateTextInput

#    updateSliderInput(
#      session = session,
#      inputId = 'sliderValue',
#      value = input$textValue
#    ) # updateSliderInput

  }) # observe

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It allows the user to change the values of a slider (`sliderInput`), which updates the text in the text box (`textInput`):

[image]

I want these to work in sync. So, instead of just the above slider > text box interaction, I want the opposite as well: text box > slider.

If you uncomment the `updateSliderInput` component, the two widgets compete against one another; an update of the one leads to an update of the other which leads to an update of the other, ...

[image]

How can this be avoided while still making the two be in sync?

Comment: I have a feeling there is a need for [`isolate(...)`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html) somewhere...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to do it would be using `observeEvent` for each input and adding a condition `if(as.numeric(input$textValue) != input$sliderValue)`. This will help you from the inputs calling each others update functions recursively. Then your app would look something like this:

```
library('shiny')
  
  # User Interface/UI
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel(
      'Slider and Text input update'
    ), # titlePanel
    
    mainPanel(
      
      # Slider input
      sliderInput(
        inputId = 'sliderValue',
        label = 'Slider value',
        min = 0,
        max = 1000,
        value = 500
      ), # sliderInput
      
      # Text input
      textInput(
        inputId = 'textValue',
        value = 500,
        label = NULL
      ) # textInput
      
    ) # mainPanel
    
  ) # fluidPage
  
  
  # Server logic

  server <- function(input, output, session)
  {
    observeEvent(input$textValue,{
      if(as.numeric(input$textValue) != input$sliderValue)
      {
        updateSliderInput(
          session = session,
          inputId = 'sliderValue',
          value = input$textValue
        ) # updateSliderInput
      }#if
      
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$sliderValue,{
      if(as.numeric(input$textValue) != input$sliderValue)
      {
        updateTextInput(
          session = session,
          inputId = 'textValue',
          value = input$sliderValue
        ) # updateTextInput
        
      }#if
     
    })
    
    
  }
  
  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I just tried this, it works, but if a user want to enter a value by deleting the existing input, the app closes.Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The above code can be modified a bit to fix the issue of application getting closed when the input in the test box is empty

```
   library('shiny')
   ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel('Slider and Text input update'),

                    mainPanel(
                      sliderInput(
                        inputId = 'sliderValue',
                        label = 'Slider value',
                        min = 0,
                        max = 1000,
                        value = 500
                      ),


                      textInput(
                        inputId = 'textValue',
                        value = 500,
                        label = NULL
                      )

                    ))


    # Server logic

    server <- function(input, output, session)
    {
      observeEvent(input$textValue, {
        print(input$textValue)
        if ((as.numeric(input$textValue) != input$sliderValue) &
            input$textValue != "" &  input$sliderValue != "")
        {
          updateSliderInput(
            session = session,
            inputId = 'sliderValue',
            value = input$textValue
          )
        } else {
          if (input$textValue == "") {
            updateSliderInput(session = session,
                              inputId = 'sliderValue',
                              value = 0)

          }
        }


      })

      observeEvent(input$sliderValue, {
        if ((as.numeric(input$textValue) != input$sliderValue) &
            input$sliderValue != "" & input$textValue != "")
        {
          updateTextInput(
            session = session,
            inputId = 'textValue',
            value = input$sliderValue
          )

        }

      })


    }

    # Run the application
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late to this discussion, but I have recently been having similar trouble. Only I was wanting to sync numeric inputs with slider values... Using the latest example posted here, I still had issues with infinite loops. I think that I finally found a solution to the infinite loops. Following on from Tinku's answer, I add a time delay in the part of the code where the numeric input is updated by the slider value. I believe that the slider value updates slightly slower than the numeric input, so if changing the numeric input too fast, the lag can become too much and looping occurs. I add the code below…. I set the lag to 0.3 s, which is good enough to avoid the infinite loops on my computer….

```
library('shiny')
library('shinyvalidate')


ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel('Slider and numeric input'),
            
            mainPanel(
              sliderInput(
                inputId = 'sliderValue',
                label = 'Slider value',
                min = 0,
                max = 1000,
                value = 500,
                step = 5,
              ),
              
              
              numericInput(
                inputId = 'numericValue',
                min = 0,
                max = 1000,
                value = 500,
                step = 5,
                label = "Numeric value"
              ),
              
              actionButton("Set", "Apply"),
              textOutput("value") #Paste the 'Set' value
            ))

    # Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session)
{

 v <- reactiveValues()
 #Register the current time
 v$now = Sys.time() 
 v$when = Sys.time() 

 #The saved numeric value to use in further functions/plots
 v$num = 500 # Initial value

 observeEvent(input$numericValue, {
  v$when = Sys.time()
  req(input$numericValue) 
   if (input$numericValue != input$sliderValue)
  {
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = 'sliderValue',
      value = input$numericValue
    )
  } 
})

  observeEvent(input$sliderValue, {
    v$now = Sys.time() 
    req(input$numericValue)
    if (input$numericValue != input$sliderValue  & v$now - v$when > 0.3) #I found 0.3 s a good lag to give (I believe that the slidervalue updates ~0.25 s slower than numericinput)
 {
   updateNumericInput(
     session = session,
     inputId = 'numericValue',
     value = input$sliderValue
    )   
  }

})

 #Only update the reactive value (v$num) if within the specified numeric range....
 isolate(
   observeEvent(input$Set, {
   i <- InputValidator$new()
   i$add_rule("numericValue", sv_required(message = "Number must be provided"))
   i$add_rule("numericValue", sv_gte(0))
   i$add_rule("numericValue", sv_lte(1000))
   i$enable()
   req(i$is_valid())
   v$num <- input$numericValue  #Use this reactive value in further functions/plots.....
   output$value <- renderText({paste("The syncronised value is:", v$num)})
  })
 )

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```