# Unable to lift state in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to lift state of the number of bins one level up from a module. This is a common technique in react, and I suspect shiny as well, when some data needs to be shared between different components (modules in shiny parlance)

This is the code I currently have

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
source("modules/my.R", local=my <- new.env())

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("App 1", tabName="app1"),
      menuItem("App 2", tabName="app2"),
      id="selectedMenu"
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("foo")
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
source("modules/my.R", local=my <- new.env())

server <- function(input, output) {
  reactive = reactive({3})
  callModule(my$my, "foo", numBins=reactive)
  plot <- my$myUI("foo")

  output$foo <- renderUI({
    if (input$selectedMenu == "app1") {
      return(plot)
    } else {
      return(br())
    }
    })
}
```

and this is the module

```
library(shiny)

myUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        plotOutput(outputId = ns("distPlot")),
        width=12
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      box(
        sliderInput(inputId = ns("bins"), label = "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
        width=12
      )
    )
  )
}

my <- function(input, output, session, numBins) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    numBins()

    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = numBins() + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")
  })
  observe({
    updateSliderInput(session, "bins", value=numBins())
  })
}
```

I am trying to lift numBins out at the server.R level, and inject it in the module. However, it seems that the plot is not re-rendered. Initialisation seems to work however. I get the right number of bins, but moving the slider does nothing.

Please feel free to comment on other things that look dodgy. I am just a beginner with shiny and R (I do however have experience with react)

**Edit**

I have a simpler version with just two sliders, trying to make one change when the other is moved, by having numBins shared between the two from below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
source("modules/my.R", local=my <- new.env())

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("central")
  )
)
```

```
library(shiny)
source("modules/my.R", local=my <- new.env())

server <- function(input, output) {
  numBins = reactiveVal(value=3)
  callModule(my$my, "slider1", id="slider1", numBins=numBins)
  callModule(my$my, "slider2", id="slider2", numBins=numBins)
  output$central <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      my$myUI("slider1"),
      my$myUI("slider2")
    )})
}
```

```
library(shiny)

myUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    box(
      sliderInput(inputId = ns("bins"), label = "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      width=12
    )
  )
}

my <- function(input, output, session, id, numBins) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  observeEvent(
    numBins,
      {
       cat("1234", file=stderr())
       updateSliderInput(session, ns("bins"), value=numBins())
   })
}
```

Still not working and kind of ugly to have to provide the id twice for the server function.

Comment: Do you simply want couple if sliders that are in sync i.e. the other updates when either one is moved? If yes, is using modules a must?

Comment: @Shree Precisely. I am mostly playing with what it can do compared to react at the moment. I actually found the solution but I am going to paste it tomorrow. Now I'm too busy. It was actually trivial once understood the differences.

Comment: Okay, so you don't need an answer for this anymore, right?

Comment: @Shree yes and no. I have no experience with shiny, so if you want to correct my mistakes in the code above and get the bounty, I'd love to be taught something new.  I spent the bounty points anyway, you might as well get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying to answer your edited example with two synced sliders. My solution is to let the module `return` the value of the `sliderInput`, and also receive an input `coupledValue` which is used in in `observeEvent` to update the `sliderInput` value.

**my.R**

Somewhat counterintuitively (at least to me when I first learned about it), you do **not** need to wrap the id "bins" into an `ns()` inside the `updateSliderInput()`.

```
library(shiny)

myUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    box(
      sliderInput(inputId = ns("bins"), label = "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      width=12
    )
  )
}

my <- function(input, output, session, id, coupledValue) {

  observeEvent(coupledValue(), {
    updateSliderInput(session, "bins", value=coupledValue())
    })

  return(reactive(input$bins))
}
```

**server.R**

The `numBins()` reactive becomes unnecessary, as well as the additional environment you provided within `source()`.

```
library(shiny)
source("modules/my.R")

server <- function(input, output) {
  valSlider1 <- callModule(my, "slider1", id="slider1", coupledValue = valSlider2)
  valSlider2 <- callModule(my, "slider2", id="slider2", coupledValue = valSlider1)
}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
source("modules/my.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    myUI("slider1"),
    myUI("slider2")
  )
)
```

If you want to sync to multiple inputs, you can use `return(list(input1 = ..., input2 = ...))` as your return value from the module. When you pass that whole named list into another module, e.g. with the name `coupledValues`, you will have to reference it as `coupledValues$input1()` and `coupledValues$input2()` (note the `()` after the `$`).

Comment: This is great! +1. Seems like it cleanly *"avoids"* one `observeEvent` per slider.

Comment: Great solution, how do you think this could work if one had more than two modules?

Comment: I suppose it would become cumbersome, maybe the strategy by @Thomas is the smoother way in that case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509054

Answer (score 1):

Discalimer: This answer is based on [In sync sliderInput and textInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822736/in-sync-sliderinput-and-textinput)

I am not sure if this is the best use case for shiny modules. Anyways, here's a way without using modules. Let me know if using modules is a must and I'll try and update my answer.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  lapply(1:2, function(x) {
    sliderInput(paste0("slider", x), paste0("Slider ", x), min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
  }),
  verbatimTextOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$slider1, {
    if(input$slider1 != input$slider2) {
      updateSliderInput(session, "slider2", value = input$slider1)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$slider2, {
    if(input$slider1 != input$slider2) {
      updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", value = input$slider2)
    }
  })

  output$test <- renderPrint({
    c("Slider 1" = input$slider1, "Slider 2" = input$slider2)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `return` works nice for smaller applications, though using a strategy of reactiveValues pays of in larger apps.

I found the strategy in a blog post by rTask [Communication between modules and its whims](https://rtask.thinkr.fr/communication-between-modules-and-its-whims/)

The idea is to use `r` as a `reactiveValues` and pass it to each callModule.
Inside the module, you create a new `reactiveValues` based on `r`, e.g. `r$my <- reactiveValues()`

Then you don't need to return your module output and you don't need to pass any reactive variable except for `r`

Here I edited your code according to this strategy (and a few minor things, posted already):

**ui.R**

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
source("modules/my.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        myUI("slider1"),
        myUI("slider2")
    )
)
```

**server.R**

```r
library(shiny)
source("modules/my.R")

server <- function(input, output) {
    r <- reactiveValues()

    numBins = reactiveVal(value=3)

    callModule(my, "slider1", id="slider1", r = r)
    callModule(my, "slider2", id="slider2", r = r)
}
```

**my.R**

```r
library(shiny)

myUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    box(
      sliderInput(inputId = ns("bins"), label = "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      width=12
    )
  )
}

my <- function(input, output, session, id, r) {
  r$my <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    r$my <- input$bins
  })

  observeEvent(
    r$my,
    {
      cat("1234", file=stderr())
      updateSliderInput(session, "bins", value=r$my)
    })
}
```

Comment: Fantastic how you managed to generalise the solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly too late to compete for the bounty. But as I have done the thinking, here is my contribution. This differs from all the existing answers in that it neither uses coupled sliders, nor observers.

First let me ensure I understand your intent: You want to pass the number of bins from the slider in the sub-module, back to the parent module, before passing it from the parent module into the output calculation of the (same) sub-module. (If I have misunderstood your intend, see note below for an alternative).

This would make more sense if you were passing values between two different sub-modules. Modules in Shiny are intended to pass their own values within themselves, so as to avoid cluttering the parent module.

If this is your intention, I recommend the following:

UI (essentially unchanged):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
source("modules/my.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("App 1", tabName="app1"),
      menuItem("App 2", tabName="app2"),
      id="selectedMenu"
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    uiOutput("foo")
  )
)
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)
source("modules/my.R")

server <- function(input, output) {

  resource_numBins = reactive({ # reactive value is defined
    if(exists('my_realised')
       & !is.null(my_realised$num_bin())){ # conditions to prevent errors/warnings
      return(my_realised$num_bins())
    }else{
      return(3) # required initial value
    }
  })

  # reactive value passed to module
  my_realised <- callModule(my, "foo", numBins = resource_numBins)
  # my_realised stores values returned by module

  output$foo <- renderUI({
    if (input$selectedMenu == "app1") {
      return(myUI("foo", initial_num_bins = resource_numBins()))
    } else {
      return(br())
    }
  })
}
```

Module (some white space removed):

```
library(shiny)

myUI <- function(id, initial_num_bins) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow( box(
        plotOutput(outputId = ns("distPlot")), width=12
      ) ),
    fluidRow( box(
        sliderInput(inputId = ns("bins"), label = "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1, max = 50, value = initial_num_bins),
        width=12
      ) )
  )
}

my <- function(input, output, session, numBins) { # module receives value from parent
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = numBins() + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")
  })
  return(list(num_bins = reactive({input$bins}))) # module returns slider value to parent
}
```

Note that the complexity of `resource_numBins` is due to it also being used as the initial value, and needing to persist when menu item "App 2" is selected. Without these additional requirements this reactive would simplify to:

```
resource_numBins = reactive({ # reactive value is defined
    return(my_realised$num_bins())
  })
```

As sub-modules will pass values between themselves without first needing to pass a value back to the parent, the other problem you might be seeking to solve is how to use a sub-module to update the value in a parent module. For this I suggest my existing answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708815/accessing-parent-namespace-inside-a-shiny-module). Either approach will let you use the value from the sub-module in the parent module.